# Input value doesn't display in field

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, input, innerhtml

I have this function:

```
function stringGen(len){
    var text = " ";
    var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
        text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));
    return text;
}
var commande = stringGen(8);
document.getElementById("commande").innerHTML=commande;
```

And this input:

```
<input type="text" id="commande" name="commande" class="field" >
```

I would like to display the result of the "commande" variable but it simply doesn't display and i don't know why.
Is it because the value JS object and the value HTML object are not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("commande").value=commande;
```

```js
function stringGen(len) {
  var text = '';
  var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));
  return text;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var commande = stringGen(8);
  document.getElementById("commande").value = commande;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="commande" name="commande" class="field">
```

Comment: heh few seconds earlier :)

Comment: Sorry i had to wait a bit ;)

Comment: `innerHTML` property is used to access or modify the HTML content inside an element. However, the input element is a void element in HTML, which means it cannot have any HTML content or child elements. Void elements, like input, img, or br, do not have closing tags and cannot contain other elements. Therefore, trying to access or modify innerHTML of an input element will not work as expected because it doesn't have any HTML content.